# When it comes to using react with yeoman

Tags: javascript, yeoman, reactjs, yeoman-generator

There are a ton of packages out there that have this all bundled up but I dont like the way they set up the projects and such so I was reading the [Reactjs docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#npm) on installing with npm and my confusion is:

> After installing it using npm install react or adding react to
>   package.json

- Do I add this to the `"devDependencies": {}` or ...
- for the require statement to work, do I need to include requirejs?
- Can I just do grunt serv to start everything and auto compile the jsx or do I need to do [this](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html#offline-transform)? (it seems like that might be answered for me ..... but how can I get it to auto compile the jsx when I run grunt serv)

I ask these questions and state I don't like the existing `yo ...` commands for this because they don't play nicely with bacbone.js So I was going to set this up my self. if there are any repos out there for yeoman that do this for me please point me to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dependencies vs devDependencies: for npm package.json, devDependencies are mainly used for the tooling around working on the project itself: testing tool chain and project building modules, for example. Things you'd often see in there: Mocha, Grunt, etc. So mostly for repo contributors and alike. As a consumer of React, you'd put it in dependencies, which are for modules that your code actually needs in order to work.
2. require isn't for requirejs. The naming clash is unfortunate. `require()` is part of [CommonJS](http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/). Node uses CommonJS. [Browserify](http://browserify.org) too. Here, it's assuming that you're using Browserify, or maybe doing server-side React with Node.
3. I'm not sure what you've set up to use with `grunt serve`. There's nothing magical that makes it work by default. You do need to do what the link said. The `--watch` option will look for changes to your files and auto compile the jsx to js.

Hope that helps!